# USB doesn't t boot in UEFI mode

Tags: boot, microsoft-windows

I downloaded the ISO from the official website, I installed it on the USB with Rufus, in GPT for UEFI, with FAT32. I already checked the ISO SHA256.

When trying to boot it, it does nothing, does not boot. Fast boot disabled and secure boot too.
I am currently on Windows 10.

My laptop is a ASUS X411UF with Intel i5-8250U

Answer (score 0):

Try using rufus with this parameters to boot in the UEFI USB installation/liveCD

[image]